# LED randomizer microcontroller SFF (Small Form Factor) circuit

Tags: microcontroller, led

I want 12 leds in the circuit programmed to go around at a certain speed. 17 smd leds in total. What I need to do is for the chase to randomly chose to slow down for 1 second or speed up for 1 second with a respective led come on each time it is chosen. It is using a ATMEL AT89C2051-24PU (DIP-20) microcontroller, 3v battery, 17 leds(12 for chase,3 for rotation, 2 for speed up/down notifier) , 1 switch, 1 piezo. Leds go around at the programmed speeds and clocks 1 rotation notified by an individual led 3 rotations in total. Start of rotation notified by piezo and at the end. How can I do this, can I program into the microcontroller or will I need a different one or two?

Im a novice.

Thanks

Comment: How many LEDs do you want to control?

Comment: Thanks for replying Steven. I've hopefully made it easier to do. With a bit more of the details of inventory. Ive just got a pick it 2 for program but I dont know anything about what it can do.

Comment: @iliaskafetzakis You have a [pickit2 programmer](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en023805&redirects=pickit2)? That's no good. You can only program Microchip microcontrollers (PIC) with that. For Atmel microcontrolles, you'll need another programmer.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what's being asked here. How to program a microcontroller is a little bit much to put in a single answer. Can you narrow it down a little bit?

Comment: Wow, I've just read the previous version of this question. It's much easier to understand.

Comment: lol to Rocketmagnet first one probably went way over your head, sorry if you tried to read it. I havent got the microcontrollers yet I was told this will do. Just tell me what Ill need. All Im asking m.Alin is can I program and what Ill need components wise. I can design the input after. Thanks

Comment: @iliaskafetzakis Sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking. Also, I'm not familiar with Atmel's microcontrollers.

Comment: It doesnt have to be an Atmel but I was told it was cheapest best for what I needed. I cant see why you cant understand it? all it is controlling flashing LEDs and I want to know is how! Thanks

Comment: @iliaskafetzakis - as m.Alin says, you cannot program an Atmel with a PICkit2. A PIC 16F (e.g. PIC16F1828, PIC16F690, etc) will do this easily and be as cheap as an Atmel so if you already have the programmer you might as well use one of these. To help you write the code we will need far more exact specifications of the pattern and timings involved, plus what you want the buttons to do (a basic state diagram would good)

Comment: It would probably be better if you grabbed e.g. a starter kit from Microchip (or Atmel) and went through the basic tutorials, then come back with a few specific questions one you understand a little more. It would be hard to go into enough detail all in one answer to help you through all this at once.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=DM164120-3) or [this](http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=DM164127) (PIC18F will be fine too) | More options [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en531769)

Comment: Thats great yes I can use PIC I can also get a diffrernt programmer (:

Comment: So is it possible to program the LEDs each to flash on consecutivley each with its own activation speed in the sequence chase then add some sort of a randomizer programming to choose to speed up the chase by 1 second or slow down by 1 second which is also shown by a LED as a visual notification. Can this be done through the microcontroller?

Comment: @iliaskafetzakis Yes, it can be done with a microcontroller. Actually, the easiest way to do it is with a microcontroller. As _Oli_ recommends, you should switch to a PIC, instead of buying another programmer. It's much cheaper this way.

Comment: Totally awesome (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you are a novice, Do you have any experience of C or assembly programming. As far as your question concern, your program requirement is not simple.

However i shall guide you.

You may do your work with just one microcontroller, but you need multiplexing technique for this, as your described cntroller has 15 I/Os and you are interfacing 17 LEDs, 1 push button switch and 1 buzzer.

For Buzzer one output is required.
For Push button one input is required.
For 3 rotation LEDs and 2 Speed LEDs you need 5 outputs
For 12 LEDs you may connect all 12 LEDs in 4x3 format, 12 LEDs in 4 rows and 3 coloums, which consumed 7 outputs.

So, Total 14 I/Os are consumed, 1 is still free.

I assumed that you have some basic knowledge of microcontroller programming and its all registers.

You have to make your program in modular form (module: small or a big program) and labeled them according their function name, each function has its own module. Let say LED Chaser function module name may be LED_Chaseer or LED_Chase.

Make one module for Timer function and one for switch and buzzer funcion.

ONE Timer interrupt function, where you are driving all LEDs.

One main function is obviously required for running continously. In this MAIN function, you have to read switch function first than start timer by sending timer function a value. On every timer interrupt drive LEDs as you want. and than increment or decrement timer value for LED Visual change.

From this way you can get your results.

Wish you best of Luck